# Correct usage of composite pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, uml, class-diagram, composite

I'm currently taking a course in Software Engineering (I have to).
We have a whole bunch of tasks which require us to use design patterns in Java. Normally I'm just a PHP developer, so I don't have many skills in Java, which may be a problem.

The specific problem is: We have to use the composite pattern for following problem: Create a mathematic framework to solve terms. The term could be Number (double) or "/", "-" which connect two terms, or "sin" which uses one Term.

I have to create a UML Class Diagram to.
Which is this

[image]

I'm not sure if this is right. The two main questions I got about my class diagram are:

1. Is it correct to use value, and first/second for the Composites, because they only have either 1 or 2 Terms, or should I make a list with `add`method and make sure there are exactly 1/2 items in the list?
2. Should I create another Interface for the Composite Structures (Sin, Divide, Subtract)

Am I doing it right, or did I follow a bad/wrong approach?

Thank you

Bernd

Comment: *Just to note* design pattern isn't just linked to Java. Actually, the GoF used the C++ language to illustrate their examples. Design patterns are language agnostic.

Comment: Thank you, I already knew that. But in this course we have to use Java

Comment: It looks ok for me. It's ok to use first/second. If you had more operations, you could add base classes BinaryOperation and UnaryOperation. I would just change Term to Expression. For me Term should be a terminal symbol (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_and_nonterminal_symbols).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The composite pattern really doesn't place any restrictions on *how* you represent the children of a composite node. In your case you could either have classes representing unary and binary operations or have separate classes for each operation.

The second option would look something like:

```
interface Term {
    double getValue();
}

class Constant implements Term {
    private double value;
    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Divide implements Term {
    private Term numerator;
    private Term denominator;
    public double getValue() {
        return numerator.getValue() / denominator.getValue();
    }
}
```

This is probably the closest representation of your UML. In this case there's no advantage in modelling the child terms as a `List`.

The other option I mentioned (which I would not recommend) is to have `UnaryOperation` and `BinaryOperation` classes and then define and `enum` for the operations. In this case the operation enumeration would contain the actual calculation logic. I think that's unnecessarily complex for your needs unless you have a large number of operations.

Comment: This is pretty much how my implementation looks like in Java. So my diagram represents a correct usage of the composite pattern?

Comment: Yes. Though note that Term needs to be an interface or an abstract class. It looks like you realise that in how you've modelled it.

Comment: Yep, term is an interface. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but this isn't a correct implementation of the composite pattern.  If you look at it, you'll see that you have no Composite (the object with add, remove, and getChild methods) class, and that you're aggregating the Leaf objects which you should not do.

If you're to apply the composite pattern to this problem, you need to come up with a class that contains the different operations to perform.

So, first create an abstract class called something like *FrameworkItem*.  This corresponds to *Component* on the Composite pattern diagram.  From this, derive another class called Term.  This is your Composite, and is an aggregate of FrameworkItem.  (Make sure it includes your add, remove, and getChild methods.)  Finally, derive your Leaf classes individually (Number, Sin, Subtract, Divide etc.) from *FrameworkItem* as well, using simple association rather than aggregate.

Keep in mind that your Composite's solve() method needs to take a Leaf object as parameter, which tells it which one of its children's solve() methods it needs to call.